# How can I validate that an object conforms to an interface at runtime?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Let's imagine I am deserializing JSON into a JavaScript object at runtime, for instance the body of a REST API response:

```
const json = await response.json()
```

Let's say I expect this object to conform to an interface I have declared:

```
interface ResponseRecord {
    foo: string,
    bar: number
}
```

How can I validate, at runtime, that `json` is a valid instance of the interface `ResponseRecord`?

Comment: I think that you need to validate it in your code. You can use a library like https://github.com/gcanti/io-ts/blob/master/index.md#typescript-integration or similar to help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typescript is strictly compile-time, but there are many data validation libraries for typescript. They all work more or less the same way: you define a schema structure in JS, use that schema to parse your input, and a valid input is then known to have a strong type.

One popular choice is Zod:

```js
import { z } from "zod";

// Construct a scheme in JS which can be used for runtime validation ...
const ResponseRecord = z.object({
  foo: z.string(),
  bar: z.number(), // ... or z.bigint() etc
});

// ... and get the TS type for compile-time goodness
type TResponseRecord = z.infer<typeof ResponseRecord>
// { foo: string, bar: number }

const goodInput: unknown = { foo: "hello", bar: 99 };
const typedInput: TResponseRecord = ResponseRecord.parse(input);

const badInput: unknown = { foo: "hello", bar: "world" };
ResponseRecord.parse(badInput); // throws ZodError
```

[Sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-playground-export-forked-cs1vp4?file=/index.ts)

If you're already using fp-ts then [io-ts](https://gcanti.github.io/io-ts/) is the obvious choice. If you're already using [yup](https://github.com/jquense/yup) for form validation then it has TS support bolted-on. Worth also giving a shout-out to [Myzod](https://github.com/davidmdm/myzod) which is heavily inspired by Zod but faster. There are many other options.

Comment: zod is the tail wagging the dog - the interfaces should be the records of truth, not all that z.object fluff.  It seems the best one can get is to write a zod schema that conforms to a given interface, which means a whole bunch of doubling up - first you write the interfaces, then you do it all again in a z.object.  not exactly ideal, but probably the best that can be done given interfaces are a fiction at runtime.